# Является ли данное предложение обобщенно-личным?

Tags: пословицы

Меня зовут Мария, я ученица 8 класса. Недавно мы проходили тест по теме «Односоставные предложения», в котором нужно было определить тип данных нам предложений. Одним из таких было «Будешь почитать отца и мать, узнаешь почет от своего сына». Я указала «обобщенно-личное», но преподаватель посчитала это за ошибку. Я обратилась к ней за помощью. Подумав, она ответила: «Мы же с вами договорились считать пословицы обобщённо-личными, только если глагол стоит в 3-м лице!». В учебнике написано, что глагол может стоять и во 2, и в 3-м.

Пожалуйста, помогите мне разобраться в этой ситуации и выяснить, кто из нас прав. Из-за этого была снижена оценка. Искренне благодарю вас!

Comment: А учительница к какому типу относит?

Answer (score 3):

**обобщенно-личное предложение.** Односоставное бесподлежащное предложение, главный член которого обычно выражен глаголом в форме 2-го лица единственного числа, реже в форме 1-го или 3-го лица множественного числа и обозначает действие, потенциально относимое к любому лицу. Основная функция обобщенно-личных предложений — образное выражение общих суждений, сентенций, часто воплощаемых в пословицы и поговорки. *Без труда не вынешь и рыбку из пруда. Любишь кататься — люби и саночки возить. Семь раз отмерь — один раз отрежь. Что имеем — не храним, потерявши — плачем. Клин клином вышибают. Цыплят по осени считают.* Обобщенное значение могут выражать и двусоставные предложения с подлежащим — личным местоимением, употребляемым в значении обобщенного лица. *Охотно мы дарим, что нам не надобно самим (Крылов).* См. также односоставные предложения.

*Розенталь Д. Э. и др. Словарь лингвистических терминов*

Мария, все равно не стоит портить отношения с учительницей и уж тем более переживать из-за сниженной оценки. Оценка - это цифра, не более того. Зато вы больше узнали об обобщенно-личных предложениях. Если интересует эта тема - поищите в сети, информации навалом.

P.S. Некоторые грамматисты вообще не выделяют обобщенно-личные предложения в отдельный тип из односоставных. И имеют на это резоны. Так что тема не такая простая.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы! Я тоже не хочу портить отношения с учительницей. Дело в том,что я круглая отличница, но с русским языком не все так гладко,как хотелось бы. Эта оценка была решающей в споре между 4-ой и 5-ой. Просто я знаю,что в будущем буду корить себя за то,что не нашла смелости доказать свою правоту...

Comment: Учительница относит пословицу к определенно-личным, обосновывая тем,что глагол стоит во 2-ом лице.

Comment: *>> Учительница относит пословицу к определенно-личным, обосновывая тем,что глагол стоит во 2-ом лице*


В этом тоже есть резон. Говорю же, тема не простая. P.S. Во **2-м** лице. Не во 2-ом. Это серьезная ошибка.

Comment: @Мария Из Вашего комментария: **Эта оценка была решающей в споре между 4-ой и 5-ой.** (Между четвёркой и пятёркой.) Здесь наращение НЕ требуется — это существительные,  соответствующие числам. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Четвёрка

Comment: Все-таки 2-ом вместо 2-м не такая уж и серьезная ошибка, скорее вполне допустимый вариант (хоть и режет глаза) :)

Comment: Может, не такая уж серьезная (сгустил краски), но ошибка несомненная, а не допустимый вариант.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваши замечания! Действительно,для грамотного человека неприятно такое видеть :)

Answer (score 2):

Будешь почитать отца и мать, узнаешь почет от своего сына.

Это обобщенно-личное предложение http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-156.htm#i10644

"Основное назначение обобщенно-личных предложений - образное выражение общих суждений, больших обобщений, поэтому они так широко представлены в народных пословицах: Из песни слова не выкинешь; С кем поведешься, от того и наберешься; Что посеешь, то и пожнешь".

В этих предложениях используются разные формы глагола, причем форма 2-го лица единственного числа  названа в первую очередь.

Глагол может обозначать обобщенное действие и в форме 3-го лица множественного числа изъявительного наклонения. Например: Снявши голову, по волосам не плачут (посл.);

Иногда применяются и другие формы, но в школьной практике две указанные формы являются основными.

Answer (score 1):

> Будешь почитать отца и мать, узнаешь почет от своего сына.

Во второй части этого предложения заключено указание на результат, следствие. В таких случаях между частями предложения ставится не запятая, а тире (см. [**ПАС, § 130, п. 2**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135)):

***Будешь почитать отца и мать — узнаешь почет от своего сына.***

**Бессоюзное сложное предложение**, состоит из двух  односоставных обобщённо-личных предложений.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Я полностью согласна с Вами,но в тесте почему-то вместо тире стояла запятая. Это меня тоже весьма озадачило.